# Angular 6 project inside laravel blade

Tags: laravel, angular6, laravel-blade

I am using angular 6 project in a laravel backend. I build the project with --prod and -base-href = /public/angular/dist/ and everything is great. Now i load the index html file from public/angular/dist/index.html inside a laravel blade:

```
include base_path()./public/angular/dist/index.html';
```

The blade loads perfectly the static angular deployed html file but my only problem is that the url turn into

```
mydomain.com/public/angular/dist
```

I tried with htaccess to rewrite the url but I couldn't make it. Is there any way u can help me?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the combination of Angular 2+ and  Laravel are meant to be separated projects.

In the backend you make an api with Laravel and then you can consume it from any front end: angular, react, android, etc.

In the frontend you make a service that fetch the api urls in the backend and that url responses a json, it may be in example, a list of users.

Answer (score 0):

it will works :
1. Build your angular app with following cmd :

```
ng build --prod --output-path pwa-app--base-href /pwa-app/
```

2. Copy paste angular project  build to your laravel application

[image]

3.Go to resources > views . Create app.php and paste the following code

```
<?php readfile("./pwa-app/index.html"); ?>
```

4.Add the following route inside web.php

```
Route::any('/pwa-app/{any?}',function() { return view('app'); });
```

5.Try !!!

> yourdomain/pwa-app

I hope this will works ...